# Memory tracker built on CRT Debug Heap functions

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm looking for a real time memory tracker library (or considering writing one) that is built on the [CRT Debug Heap functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). This would primarily be for performance/memory usage analysis, although it should also detect leaks.

I'm looking to get similar data to what [Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php) provides except integrated into a program (not an external tool).

If there is a library that already suits my needs that would be great. If not, could you point me towards some resources for writing one and possibly list some pros and cons of building it on top of the CRT debug heap functions as opposed to overloading new and delete and writing a memory tracker singleton (or suggest a different better route to take).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the details MemoryValidator provides from just the CRT debug heap. It doesn't supply a callstack or even file/line without #defining new (evil! and breaks placement new).

Comment: #include <crtdbg.h> and _CrtSetBreakAlloc(request_number); can break your code in case you can set exact order number...

Answer (score 1):

Obvious you are on the windows platform, I suggest the [Visual leak detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) lib.

In most scenario memory tracking is use to detect memory leak, but only print the memory allocation file name and line number is not enough to find out the real problem, you need the backtrace for the leaked memory.

Comment: This appears to only work for 32bit, I definitely need 64bit support (sorry, didn't say that before). I haven't looked in depth yet, but can this do more than dump a leak report in the output window? I need performance stats in run-time.

Comment: I think vlk will working on 64bit windows platform. What kind of performance stats you're looking for?